# How to make a progress bar change value with a specific speed depending on time cumulated

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a progress bar as a healthbar in a game. The healthbar regenerates 10 pr millisecond for now because i like the smoothness. But if the delay increases it would take a lot longer to regenerate.

Aren't there any formular to calculate some kind of factor for this? so the lifebar would regenerate within a constant time no matter what. If the delay is 2 seconds it would just make the regen more choppy and if delay is 1 millisecond it would just update more.

Comment: What do you mean by "delay"? If you have regeneration timer events firing once every second, doesn't matter how laggy flash gets — it'll update in timeframes set by the timer. That's the whole idea of having a timer execute updates in comparison with having ENTER_FRAME events.

Comment: Well that wasn't quite what I meant.

Comment: Think of it as this. I have a max value, current value, min value and a regeneration value in this case those a like this.: max = 100, current = 1, min = 0(dead), and regeneration = 10. I also have a timer and a listener. Every time the timer triggers the current value is going to be increased by the regeneration value unless the current value is equal to or greater than the max valuue. So if I set the timer trigger delay to 25 ms the current value will be increased every 25 ms by 10 and it would take 250 ms to gain full life. (max value)

Comment: but if I set the timer trigger delay equal to 1 ms it would only take 10 ms.

Comment: And what I need is some kind of algorithm to make the time constant so  it will take let's say 10 seconds no matter what if you have 10 for regeneration and let's say 20 seconds if you have 5 for regeneration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to the problem you're facing, worth looking at, and though the first one is not actually what your question is about, I feel like using it is sufficient for most simple game loops.

The first idea relies on having one target framerate (the rate in which your game operates, but executing some actions on certain frames (let's say once a 4 frames, once a 2 frames and so on). The code to the solution would look like this:

```
var updates:Number = 0;
var t:Timer = new Timer(20, 50); // 50 FPS
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _onTimer);
t.start();

function _onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    var count = t.currentCount;
    if (count % 5 == 0) // replace 5 with any delay parameter here
    {
        updates++;
        trace(updates);
    }
}
```

If you'd run the example above, you'd see that we only execute 10 updates, though running for a second on a 50 FPS. That's because of getting the count of timer events fired and seeing whether it's a 5th, 10th, 15th and etc. time the event has fired. You can change the factor from 5 to whatever you want — can execute code on every 10th or 20th or 2nd frame and even have some code execute on one frame intervals and another block on different ones, by havin, say another check of (if count % 3 == 0).

---

Now, moving on to the solution you asked for, the code would be like this:

```
// rate in which health regenerates (points per second)
var regenRate:Number = 10;

// starting health
var health:Number = 20;

function _onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    // get timer delay (between timer events)
    var timerDelay:Number = t.delay;
    // calculate how much health to regenerate based on regen rate
    // ((delay / 1 second) * regeneration rate per second)
    var regenAmount:Number = timerDelay / 1000 * regenRate;
    // add that to health and set it to 100 if more than that
    health += regenAmount;
    if (health >= 100)
        health = 100;
}

// takes 8 seconds to complete, no matter what delay
var t:Timer = new Timer(20);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _onTimer);
t.start();
```

You may want to round (using `Math.round(expression)` or `uint(expression)`, when calculating `regenAmount`, since without rounding it produces some really ugly numbers (as would one expect with floating point Numbers).